# Android Studio does not show layout preview(no error occurs also)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Android Studio does not display a preview of the layout. No errors or warnings are showing. I already try this solution `Invalidate Caches/ Restart.`

[image]

### XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/peripherals_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/peripheral_list_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/peripheral_list_empty"/>

</RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     tools:context=".MainActivity">

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txt"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Hello World!"
             app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


      <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer if you think you can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

If the system UI is **on** Listview will not show. Look for an icon with eye and unmark **show system UI**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).